# Why am I not able to apply the update "KB2670838" to my computer?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, updates, setup

**Background**: I am trying to run the game "Leo's Fortune" on my computer. It shows the error: "Could not update DXGI factory! Try updating your Windows system." To try and solve this problem, listening to [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vsy4mWlhxqA&feature=youtu.be), i first ran the automatic Windows Update, which didn't help. Then reading [this](https://steamcommunity.com/app/355630/discussions/0/527274698152050696/#p2), i manually downloaded the "KB2670838" update from [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36805). I tried running it, and it gives me the error: "The update is not applicable to your computer."

[image: http://i.imgur.com/IHXj3l6.gif]

**Steps i tried**:

1. Reading from [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-update/unable-to-install-update-the-update-is-not/70a25adf-8deb-4965-8b9b-2c5072d0277a), i ran the `sfc /scannow` on Adminstrator Priveleges *cmd*.
2. Then reading from [here](http://www.askvg.com/fix-the-update-is-not-applicable-to-your-computer-error-message-while-installing-windows-8-1-preview-from-store/), i tried `Expand -F:* E:\MSUpdate.msu E:\`, where i had renamed the downloaded package file to `MSUpdate.msu`. Then, i wrote the command:

   ```
   DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:E:\Windows6.1-KB2670838-x86.cab
   ```

   it shows the error: `Error: 0x800f081e` `The specified package is not applicable to the image`. Reading from [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/windows-update-error-0x800f081f), i tried running the command:

   ```
   DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /scanhealth
   ```

   and it says that `The /scanhealth option is not recognizable in this context`. *Edit*: The `scanhealth` option seems to be available only in Windows 8 and above, so no luck there.

I have finally run into a brick wall. What can i do to install this pesky update? Any help on the Leo's Fortune installation issue is most welcome, and please do advise me in a comment if it is appropriate to open a question on that topic on this site. Thank you for your help!

**Note:** I have included a number of links which might be required for answering the question, or just checking the sources of my steps. If someone more enlightened feels these links are not necessary, feel free to edit out these links.

Comment: x86 is for 32Bit. Do you use a 32Bit Windows? If you use a 64 Bit Windows, download the -x64 version.

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, i use 32-bit Windows. I checked in Computer --> System Properties, and it says that mine is a 32-bit OS!

Comment: the doesn't apply also ahppens if the update is already installed or the installed files are already newer as the files from the update.

Comment: @magicandre Is there a way to check that? (And, if that is true, then my computer is probably doomed to never play Leo's Fortune :\ . That reminds me of DOOM...)

Comment: use expand again to also extract the CAB and check the file versions and compare them to the file version in the system32 folder.

Answer (score 1):

Why is the update “KB2670838” not applicable to my computer?

Answer: [KB2670838 won't download on Windows 7 SP1 - for download of Interenet Explorer 11](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-windows_7/kb2670838-wont-download-on-windows-7-sp1-for/f6d8495d-7b14-46dc-a2d8-6230be16024a)

Some computers that have a combination of Intel and AMD video cards in a hybrid configuration, that is incompatible with this KB2670838 update. To resolve this issue, you may have to install the update [2834140](https://support.microsoft.com/kb/2834140).

[Direct download link for KB2670838](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=fc456c44-3bf8-483e-9d49-9e45c02b8a41&displaylang=en-us)

If the video card installed in the computer is not in a hybrid configuration or the update KB2834140 is already installed, then try the steps mentioned below and check the issue. After performing each method first try to install KB2670838 update.

### Method 1

Run System File Checker as it can helps users to scan for corruptions in Windows system files and restore corrupted files.

[Use the System File Checker tool to repair missing or corrupted system files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833)

### Method 2

Run the System Update Readiness tool. This tool runs a one-time scan for inconsistencies that may prevent future servicing operations. You may download it from the link below.
[Fix Windows corruption errors by using the DISM or System Update Readiness tool](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/947821)

### Method 3

the issue still persists, so try to install the updates after resetting Windows update components. You may try to do it by running the Microsoft fixit from the link below.
[How do I reset Windows Update components?](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058)

If the issue does not get fixed after running the fixit, then try to reset the components manually. I would suggest you to follow section, **”Manually reset Windows Update components”** from the article mentioned above and check if it helps.

**How do I reset Windows Update components?**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971058

Comment: Unfortunately the link is to this question itself, and not to the intended answer! Also, the site did not show such a question in the list of questions that may already have my answer. Could you please post the answer again? Thanks!

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

[Update for Windows 7 x64, x86](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36805)

1) Choose x64 or x86,

2) Download

3) Install

4) Restart the computer

5) Run game and play

Comment: I have already downloaded precisely that file, and it is that file which refuses to install!